# Prevent tombstones creation

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I need to perform an insert to Cassandra table without creating tombstones for any column. I am using a query similar to this :

`insert into my_table(col1,col2,col3) values(val1,val2,null)`

where col1, col2 and col3 are all the attributes in my_table.
Is there any other solution or workaround to prevent tombstone creation for say `col3` apart from passing only non-null attributes in our query and letting cassandra set the remaining attributes to null?

Comment: What you're using to insert data?

Answer (score 5):

Don't include `col3` in your insert and it just wont set anything.

```
insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(val1,val2)
```

If curious about structure on disk, do a `nodetool flush` and run sstabledump on the sstable created to see difference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried this already and it works but is there something I can do to prevent tombstone creation using the original query ?

Comment: you cant, an explicit null is a tombstone since it cant know if there was data there before on other node, it has to mask it.

Answer (score 4):

If you insert null values, Cassandra will create tombstones. If you know that col3 will be null, don't use it in your query.

```
insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(val1,val2)
```

I would suggest two really good articles on the subject

- [Common Problems with Cassandra Tombstones](https://opencredo.com/cassandra-tombstones-common-issues/)
- [About Deletes and Tombstones in Cassandra](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using prepared statements you can use the "unset" functionality that was [introduced in Cassandra 2.2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7304), which lets you use leave prepared statement variables without values and without creating tombstones on the server. It is supported in the [Java driver 3.0.0](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-java-driver-3-0-0-released#unset-values) and other drivers.